# contents in all files not parse using grep in ansible

Tags: ansible, devops

I am looking to parse the lines contain word "harddisk" in two different files such as file1.txt and file2.txt.

with below ansible command am able to get only contents in file2.txt. kindly advise.

```
---

- name: find file name with .txt extension
  shell: find /root -name "file*.txt" -print
  register: "files"

- debug:
    var: files

- name: find word harddisk in the file contents and output to result.txt in the destination server.
  shell:  cat "{{ item }}" |grep -i 'harddisk' > /root/test/result.txt
  with_items:
    - "{{ files.stdout_lines }}"
  args:
     executable: /bin/bash
  register: output
```

Comment: Does the debug shows all the files in the `stdout_lines`? Is it better with `with_items: "{{ files.stdout_lines }}"`? BTW it's better to use ad-hoc modules instead of calling shell commands, e.g. the [`find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) to search for files. (And also `cat $file | grep -i 'harddisk'` is equivalent to the simpler `grep -i 'harddisk' $file`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the list of files

```yaml
    my_files:
      - file1.txt
      - file2.txt
```

and the content

```sh
shell> cat file1.txt
foo
harddisk A
harddisk B
bar

shell> cat file2.txt
foo
harddisk C
harddisk D
bar
```

The task below grep the lines from the files

```yaml
    - shell: "cat {{ item }} | grep harddisk"
      register: files
      loop: "{{ my_files }}"
```

Then, the task below creates the list of the lines

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ files.results|
                     map(attribute='stdout_lines')|
                     list|flatten }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list
```

gives

```yaml
    "my_list": [
        "harddisk A",
        "harddisk B",
        "harddisk C",
        "harddisk D"
    ]
```

To keep the source of the lines, the task below creates a dictionary with the data

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ dict(my_files|
                          zip(files.results|
                              map(attribute='stdout_lines')|
                              list)) }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_dict
```

gives

```yaml
    "my_dict": {
        "file1.txt": [
            "harddisk A",
            "harddisk B"
        ],
        "file2.txt": [
            "harddisk C",
            "harddisk D"
        ]
    }
```